# Specifying correct interaction terms in logistic regression

Tags: logistic, interaction

My issue is with correctly specifying and interpreting interactions terms in a logistic regression. I have not found any threads that has addressed this. I hope my explanation of the issue is clear.

The data has two continuous independent variables (IV) called **value** and **meters**. There is no correlation between the two IVs. The two IVs are used to predict an outcome (yes=1, no=0). Here is the sample of the data where the IV have been normalized (min/max) not standardized:

```
#Sample of data 
structure(list(outcome = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    value = c(0.368748949810643, 0.331407447619786, 0.229177168560239, 
    0.263652461643853, 0.398364289684232, 0.298408882340016, 
    0.337650419429472, 0.331407447619786, 0.298408882340016, 
    0.53519588455026, 0.131929634081714, 0.773617950805899, 0.279143562500808, 
    0.205788643736994, 0.386821900810423, 0.49966393940569, 0.300861478408107, 
    0.199409955148836, 0.28220688407202, 0.82296715653961, 0.140104954308685, 
    0.0167060891594608, 0.016857962697274, 0.0214141688316724, 
    0.0214141688316724, 0.0520926234699549, 0.0232366512854318, 
    0.180425762922176, 0.180425762922176, 0.0252110072770044, 
    0.0252110072770044, 0.0205029276047927, 0.0192879393022865, 
    0.0211104217560459, 0.0856566753266897, 0.0496626468649424, 
    0.0505738880918221, 0.0856566753266897, 0.0256666278904442, 
    0.0176173303863404, 0.0262741220416974, 0.0156429743947678, 
    0.0882288314139103, 0.0505738880918221, 0.0294634663357762, 
    0.0235403983610583, 0.0364270296121085, 0.174047074334018, 
    0.0906071063890289, 0.093877234479817, 0.106214535913245, 
    0.093877234479817, 0.174047074334018, 0.0362977755373738, 
    0.380608011167552, 0.0391833727558261, 0.0241478925123115, 
    0.0150354802435147, 0.0241478925123115, 0.0968953171248724, 
    0.0186804451510334, 0.0968953171248724, 0.0476882908733698, 
    0.0192879393022865, 0.111171429679321, 0.111171429679321, 
    0.0203510540669795, 0.0280966044954567, 0.0490551527136893, 
    0.0159467214703944, 0.111171429679321, 0.111171429679321, 
    0.0441951995036643, 0.0253628808148177, 0.119676347796864, 
    0.0399427404448925, 0.152177284888906, 0.175333152377629, 
    0.152177284888906, 0.122862460739075, 0, 0.0301097367094498, 
    0.322340274277147, 0, 0.322340274277147, 0.714161076427934, 
    0.776144867966963, 0.182170692931095, 0.150955833882663, 
    0.640583194385203, 0.0590788062093657, 0.080948595654478, 
    0.080948595654478, 0.0590788062093657, 0.329623741388447, 
    0.0747023924929233, 0.376743314332984, 0.736160119947781, 
    0.561059624904675, 0.151996329184278, 0.151996329184278, 
    0.228398412759962, 0.124348882598524, 0.0799048690009952, 
    0.775996225781018, 0.419403621699174, 0.229736192433466, 
    0.149766696395104, 0.389675184510192, 0.803792314552716, 
    0.526849302674267, 0.31728643995502, 0.225425569041064, 0.390864321997751, 
    0.149320769837269, 0.482130624167927, 0.146050641746481, 
    0.168198327452273, 0.578004834102395, 0.330515594504117, 
    0.39175617511342, 0.144266935515142, 0.395174945390153, 0.0969987203846601, 
    0.0825804283480037, 0.493873356857575, 0.304800496335647, 
    0.493873356857575, 0.129551359106596, 0.186629958509442, 
    0.117659984231003, 0.0510295087052619, 0.186629958509442, 
    0.500116328667261, 0.0739591815631988, 0.618732793051301, 
    0.280274535654736, 0.169338994661807, 0.169338994661807, 
    0.0984851422441092, 0.08035079555883, 0.0686080628691819, 
    0.105917251541355, 0.0977419313143847, 0.0977419313143847, 
    0.105917251541355, 0.0686080628691819, 0.426092520066695, 
    0.100566132847338, 0.359500820763375, 0.38476999237401, 0.116768131115333, 
    0.368865278477904, 0.0987824266159991, 0.440659454289296, 
    0.386405056419404, 0.171914382100896, 0.137726679333566, 
    0.0871883361122959, 0.397404578179327, 0.0934313079219822, 
    0.257532281205165, 0.0647433660346142, 0.169387464939832, 
    0.111862938979151, 0.0868910517404061, 0.0868910517404061, 
    0.284882443419029, 0.121673323251516, 0.238060154846382, 
    0.151104476068608, 0.0900125376452493, 0.151104476068608, 
    0.0900125376452493, 0.0934313079219822, 0.0536113588480877, 
    0.169387464939832, 0.0934313079219822, 0.293949616761668, 
    0.519885739397934, 0.293949616761668, 1, 0.29974666201352, 
    0.192278361575349, 0.904869000995256, 0.399188284410666, 
    0.212493698863857, 0.399188284410666, 0.212493698863857, 
    0.162103997828532, 0.105619967169465, 0.246086832887407, 
    0.162103997828532, 0.641475047500872, 0.0909043907609187, 
    0.146050641746481, 0.211007277004408, 0.211007277004408, 
    0.146050641746481, 0.0909043907609187), meters = c(0.0484629861982434, 
    0.187243831033041, 0.444123797574237, 0.402969468841489, 
    0.249874529485571, 0.201589293182769, 0.208030112923463, 
    0.0936323713927227, 0.124539941447093, 0.489115432873275, 
    0.737470723546633, 0.0249634044332915, 0.708071936428273, 
    0.621183605186115, 0.746340443329151, 0.683683605186115, 
    0.579360100376412, 0.478199498117942, 0.381038268506901, 
    0.231937473860309, 0.309859891258887, 0.0484368465077374, 
    0.388592639063153, 0.746340443329151, 1, 0.124289000418235, 
    0.444123797574237, 0.249874529485571, 0.182172731074864, 
    0.489115432873275, 0.68129443747386, 0.27258469259724, 0.821099958176495, 
    0.873640736093685, 0.818224592220828, 0.58202634880803, 0.689774153074028, 
    0.798044751150146, 0.122229192806357, 0.188153492262652, 
    0.0503973232956922, 0.240955667084902, 0.166771225428691, 
    0.0390004182350481, 0.708176495190297, 0.62107904642409, 
    0.731231702216646, 0.682951693851945, 0.579360100376412, 
    0.474356963613551, 0.44487139272271, 0.490276035131744, 0.658981597657884, 
    0.125470514429109, 0.174430154746968, 0.309859891258887, 
    0.0578209953994145, 0.428272689251359, 0.153805938937683, 
    0.0484368465077374, 0.388566499372647, 0.106780635717273, 
    0.161020493517357, 0.458995713090757, 0.305241896695943, 
    0.253798985780008, 0.521155897114178, 0.587812107904642, 
    0.126803638644918, 0.785105604349644, 0.772976787954831, 
    0.804448975324132, 0.643585319949812, 0.0888488080301129, 
    0.0245190296946884, 0.707810539523212, 0.68271643663739, 
    0.579360100376412, 0.658981597657884, 0.00595984943538269, 
    0.225533249686324, 0.334431200334588, 0.0484107068172313, 
    0.24017147636972, 0.130280217482225, 0.020310539523212, 0.721063362609787, 
    0.437134044332915, 0.252248013383522, 0.0705248849853618, 
    0.734159347553325, 0.680625261396905, 0.580719364282727, 
    0.64219991635299, 0.400564617314931, 0.486511919698871, 0.125941028858218, 
    0.115677017984107, 0.0879339188624007, 0.253816394813885, 
    0.280740276035132, 0.0514951902969469, 0.407831451275617, 
    0.244719782517775, 0.00627352572145546, 0.240798828941865, 
    0.403021748222501, 0.641468005018821, 0.579307820995399, 
    0.0271329987452949, 0.352833542450857, 0.371131325805102, 
    0.232590966122961, 0.169907988289419, 0.306043496445002, 
    0.439721873693015, 0.5193956503555, 0.0209117524048515, 0.915594939355918, 
    0.865066917607695, 0.541980342952739, 0.574498117942284, 
    0.265213299874529, 0.371340443329151, 0.233009201171058, 
    0.0144291091593476, 0.279642409033877, 0.0457967377666249, 
    0.239125888749477, 0.579464659138436, 0.60461104140527, 0.643820577164366, 
    0.486198243412798, 0.306775407779172, 0.402969468841489, 
    0.0230552070263488, 0.232852363028022, 0.0987557507319113, 
    0.168653283145128, 0.374921580928482, 0.307350480970305, 
    0.77258469259724, 0.742680886658302, 0.72150773734839, 0.624712463404433, 
    0.719730238393977, 0.685853199498118, 0.444322459222083, 
    0.522898368883312, 0, 0.135246758678377, 0.279642409033877, 
    0.779642409033877, 0.480133835215391, 0.216698034295274, 
    0.000365955667084908, 0.132214554579674, 0.277132998745295, 
    0.403021748222501, 0.582340025094103, 0.643820577164366, 
    0.773055207026349, 0.812996654119615, 0.0432873274780427, 
    0.857120451693852, 0.874947720618988, 0.781890422417399, 
    0.563101212881639, 0.594730238393977, 0.299822250104559, 
    0.339293182768716, 0.41159556670849, 0.268768297783354, 0.325805102467587, 
    0.156263069845253, 0.240276035131744, 0.00026139690506065, 
    0.119615223755751, 0.122072354663321, 0.0486721037222919, 
    0.145075282308657, 0.133364700961941, 0.197354663320786, 
    0.338927227101631, 0.394134253450439, 0.428115851108323, 
    0.476787954830615, 0.518925135926391, 0.563937682977834, 
    0.696152237557507, 0.724121706398996, 0.769500209117524, 
    0.787954830614806, 0.00595984943538269, 0.559807611877875, 
    0.515108741112505, 0.486198243412798, 0.393245503973233, 
    0.424822250104559, 0.476787954830615)), row.names = c(NA, 
200L), class = "data.frame")
```

Separately, they are considered as main effects. When modelled separately, both have p-values < 0.05:

```
#IV = meters 
model <- glm(outcome ~ meters, data = df, family= binomial)
summary(model)

#output
Call:
glm(formula = outcome ~ meters, family = binomial, data = df)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-1.94020  -0.24794  -0.02802  -0.00336   2.59098  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value    Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   1.7219     0.5013   3.435    0.000594 ***
meters      -18.5005     3.6270  -5.101 0.000000338 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 169.084  on 199  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  77.371  on 198  degrees of freedom
AIC: 81.371

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 8
```

```
#IV: value
model <- glm(outcome ~ value, data = df, family= binomial)
summary(model)

#Output
Call:
glm(formula = outcome ~ value, family = binomial, data = df)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.4279  -0.5485  -0.4605  -0.4091   2.2572  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value          Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -2.5176     0.3282  -7.672 0.000000000000017 ***
value         3.0895     0.8801   3.511          0.000447 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 169.08  on 199  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 156.89  on 198  degrees of freedom
AIC: 160.89

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

The coefficients in both cases are correct in terms of the direction of change, where **value** is positive and **meters** is negative. Meaning, that meters represents "proximity" and value represents "exposure".

With that being said, together they actually have a conditional relationship, where the effect of **value** on the outcome (yes/no) is conditional to **value's** relationship with **meters**. In other words, the closer someone is in proximity (meters) to the exposure level (values), the more it will influence the outcome.

I have tried specifying this relationship:

```
model <- glm(outcome ~ value + meters + value*meters, data = df, family= binomial)
summary(model)

#output
Call:
glm(formula = outcome ~ value + meters + value * meters, family = binomial, 
    data = df)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-2.01741  -0.24157  -0.03552  -0.00525   2.43956  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)    1.1481     0.7867   1.459  0.14448   
value          1.9520     2.2231   0.878  0.37990   
meters       -14.7932     5.3112  -2.785  0.00535 **
value:meters -14.1441    18.6979  -0.756  0.44938   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 169.084  on 199  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  76.527  on 196  degrees of freedom
AIC: 84.527

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 8
```

However, I am not sure if my interpretation of this is correct. **Value** is no longer significant but **meters** still is and the interaction term is also **not** significant. My interpretation is that:

- When **Value** < 0, it will have less influence on the outcome but when **Meters** < 0, it will have influence on the outcome
- When **Value** > 0, it will have more influence on the outcome, but when **Meters** > 0, it will have less influence on the outcome

If this interpretation is correct, it is not what I am hoping to model. What I actually want to say, is:

- When **Value** > 0 and **Meters** < 0, it will have an influence on the outcome
- When **Value** < 0 and **Meters** > 0, it will have less influence on the outcome

Any help and clear explanation (in simple terms) would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Try to plot the the marginal effects of meters on outcome by value, and vice-versa. When the two main effects are continuous, usually you can't really do much interpretation of the interaction from the average coeficients

Comment: What are the meanings of the variables ?  What is your research question ? Why have you normalised the variables by min/max

Comment: @RobertLong - the data represents two groups when exposed to different light levels, in a real setting. The research question goes beyond the data, but it is to determine which directionality of light sources influences discomfort. I have modelled this already as a univariate model. However, distance was observed to greatly differentiate the two groups, hence to improve the model, I would like to add that, but am struggling to specify this relationship. Regarding normalisation, this was to make interpretation of the coefficients easier, although any suggestions would be welcomed!

Comment: So `meters` is the distance from the ligth source ? What is `value` ? What is the `outcome` ?

Comment: @RobertLong - yes, meter is the distance from the light source. The value is the light source intensity. The outcome is action = 1, no action = 0. Meaning, that they physically took an action to indicate their discomfort.

Comment: OK. Is each data point for a different subject, or all the data for the same subject or do you have multiple subjects  with repeated measures ?

Comment: @RobertLong, it was a within-subject observational/experimental setting that involved observing a group of people over time. Every time someone took an action, they were recorded as 1 and then all the rest who were present were recorded as 0.

Comment: That is very confusing. Please can you explain the experimental design, and how it relates to the data, completely.

Comment: Sorry (typo). This is all in a real setting with the same group of people, where some repeatedly took an action, some only once and others none. But because this was observed over time with the same group of people, the people who didn't take an action before, took an action at another point in the day in the day because they were closer at that time. If that makes sense? I want to show how distance is a factor to this irrespective of the direction of the light source. So if the intensity is high and they are close, they will take an action.

Comment: OK I think the models you have fitted may not be appropriate for this study design, but I have tried to answer the question asked. I would suggest asking a new question with full details about the study design.

Comment: @RobertLong the points raised were very useful. I will come back with a new question after considering your comments. Thanks again for taking the time to review my question!

Comment: You're welcome. I will be happy to look at your new question, but I'm quite busy at the moment so I might not see it. So, feel free to @ me here, to let me know when you've posted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion.

First, just a very minor point with your R code. The way to specify the interaction is `value:meters`. When you uses the `*` it does specify the interaction, but also the main effects too, which you have already included. So you could just write that model as `outcome ~ value * meters`

Second, it is not clear, why you are interpreting the output of the model that includes the interaction in terms of the main effects being less than zero. In the supplied data, both variables never take a negative value (since you have normalized them to min-max).

Third, I don't think normalisation is very useful here.

Fourth, it is not clear why you went from two bivariate models to one with both main effects and their interaction. Why have you omitted the model `outcome ~ value + meters` model ?

From these models I would say that there is very little evidence that the association of either `value` or `meters` with the outcome varies depending on the other one. It is clear that there is a strong association of `meters` with the outcome. If `value` is a potential confounder of the `meters` - `outcome` association or you are sure that there is an association `value` with the outcome and `value` is not caused (either directly or indirectly) by `meters`, then I would also include `value` in the model.

However, as discussed in the comments, there appears to be repeated measures of participants in this experiment. As such, the models presented in the OP are not appropriate, since there will be dependencies within subjects. A model that includes random intercepts for subjects might be appropriate (ie a glmm) but more detail about how the experiment was conduction would be needed. Therefore I suggest asking a new question about how to model your data, giving full details about how the exsperiment was conducted along with your research questions.